# UISearchBar makes UITableViewController scrolling too low (IOS11)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

On my `UITableViewController` the tableview scrolls too low. What I mean by that is that when scrolling to the bottom the last row is actually located way higher than the middle of the screen leaving a big white space on the bottom (lower half) of the screen.

I´m using a tableview with two collection views within some of the cells (if that might be important).

When I "pull to refresh", the tableview scrolls correctly until the view loads again.

EDIT:

So I found out that the issue only occurs when I add my UISearchBar as the header view of my table view instead of adding it to my navigationItem (IOS11).

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: can you post all your relevant code?, I mean `numberOfRows`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` without that we can't help you

Comment: You might wanna use "Debug UI Hiearchy" feature of Xcode. Try google it :)

Comment: Re posting "all your relevant code", please don't bury us in a ton of irrelevant code. Only share [the bare minimum necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But if we cannot reproduce the problem, it's hard for us to help you.

Comment: But the problem is either (a) the `frame` of the table view itself; (b) the height of that last row; or (c) `numberOfRows` is returning a value that is too large and you have a bunch of blank cells. By debugging via the "Debug View Hierarchy" button (as suggested by Dominik) can help identify diagnose which of these is likely to be the case.